# Qt - custom decimal point and thousand separator

Tags: c++, qt, localization, qt4

How can I convert a number (double) to string, with custom decimal point and thousand separator chars?

I've seen QLocale, but I don't want to choose the localization country, but rather specify my own decimal point and thousand separator chars.

Thanks

Comment: I can't help but ask - why is it necessary to use custom separators? Are you parsing a list and forced to use decimals (or periods) for delimiters?

Comment: Since it's math app client wants options to specify custom decimal point and thousand separator chars. Why these irrelevant questions...

Answer (score 14):

Qt doesn't support custom locale. But to deal with just group and decimal point characters is trivial:

```
const QLocale & cLocale = QLocale::c();
QString ss = cLocale.toString(yourDoubleNumber, 'f');
ss.replace(cLocale.groupSeparator(), yourGroupChar);
ss.replace(cLocale.decimalPoint(), yourDecimalPointChar);
```

BTW, spbots' question is not irrelevant. More detail about the goal always helps and it could lead to different approach that may serve you better.

Comment: This code fails if, for example, one wants to use German notation (using `.` as group separator and `,` as a decimal point).

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you do it just using the std::lib (no QT).  Define your own numpunct-derived class which can specify decimal point, grouping character, and even the spacing between groupings.  Imbue an ostringstream with a locale containing your facet.  Set the flags on that ostringstream as desired.  Output to it and get the string from it.

```
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class my_punct
    : public std::numpunct<char>
{
protected:
    virtual char do_decimal_point() const {return ',';}
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const {return '.';}
    virtual std::string do_grouping() const  {return std::string("\2\3");}
};

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os.imbue(std::locale(os.getloc(), new my_punct));
    os.precision(2);
    fixed(os);
    double x = 123456789.12;
    os << x;
    std::string s = os.str();
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

1.234.567.89,12

Comment: And for a Unicode-based thousands separator, e.g. Narrow No-Break Space U+202F, you can use `std::basic_stringstream<wchar_t>`, `std::numpunct<wchar_t>` and `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t>`. Live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a45e2feab1ef453).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use arg of QString.

```
QString str = QString("%L1").arg(yourDouble);
```

Answer (score 3):

for qml users:

```
function thousandSeparator(input){
    return input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: The answer is perfectly appropriate for me the way it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want QLocale perhaps you could do a simple conversion (with QString::number, for example) and then replace the desired characters afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

pretty horrible, but got the job done

```
double doubleNumber = 5234556.3545;
int precision = 2;

QString stringNumber = QString::number(doubleNumber, 'f', precision);

for(int point = 0, i = (stringNumber.lastIndexOf('.') == -1 ? stringNumber.length() : stringNumber.lastIndexOf('.')); i > 0; --i, ++point)
{
    if(point != 0 && point % 3 == 0)
    {
        stringNumber.insert(i, ',');
    }
}
```