# How to set specific char as group separator in QLocale?

Tags: c++, qt, qlocale

Each locale in Qt have different symbols used as group separator ( ',', '.' or 0xa0 for example).

Is it possible somehow for Qt application to use all settings for current locale and override char used as group separator? So it will be automatically used by all default implementations of validators and "toString" methods.

PS: by current locale I mean locale obtained by QLocale::system(), and replaced by QLocale::setDefault(locale)

Edit on duplicate suggestion:
I need not just replace group and decimal separators for double->string conversion, but backward as well. So user could input double value in different edit widgets with suggested symbols and default Qt implementation will accept it ( for example Q*Validator and QDoubleSpinBox use system locale to validate input, and if there will be non-default characters - input will be rejected).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt - custom decimal point and thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035356/qt-custom-decimal-point-and-thousand-separator)

Comment: I saw this question. All solutions cover just part of the problem - output. Main issue is that with that way I need to subclass for QDoubleSpinBox and QDaoubleValidator, to be able to accept input. At this point it looks like only solution. Digging into Qt sources only increasing my faith, that there are no simple way for me.

Comment: Yep there is a little annoyance to subclass QDoubleSpinBox, QDaoubleValidator and any other component you would need to use.But that is 5-10 code line solution so it's not the worst thing. There is also an option to make modifications to Qt sources but in my opinion that would take a lot more work and knowledge.

Comment: If talking about Qt sources - I could just add another line of locale definition to locale_data in qlocale_data_p.h. But that will add complication to update of 3rd party. Now I'm sticking to subclassing, looks like there are no magic "single line solution".